# Is there a 'Remember Selection' tool or option in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, save, selections

As I'm working with developing a "gear" concept with the **[Extension > Render > Gear > Gear](http://inkscapetutorials.org/2008/05/01/drawing-gears-in-inkscape-a-howto-by-nicu/)** tool (in [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/)) I'm finding that I am constantly selecting a large group of 'specific' nodes in my shape. Each time I try something new with those nodes and then have to undo, I have to meticulously re-select each node again. It's tedious and I wondered if there was some kind of 'remember selection' option for working with large numbers of arbitrary nodes within a drawing?

Answer (score 2):

No, there is not.

There are a few useful shortcuts for re-selecting nodes though:

- Drag the mouse (and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+drag) to select a bunch of nodes
- Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd> to "grow" the selection with adjacent nodes
- Use <kbd>!</kbd> to invert the node selection.

Take a look at the Node Tool's [keyboard shortcuts](https://inkscape.org/en/doc/keys048.html#d0e2973); you may find some of these can help you get your selection back faster.

Comment: I'll probably get my hand slapped by the mods... BUT... would it be worthwhile to maybe try to learn how to build an extension that would do this?

Comment: An extension (or contribute code directly upstream, if you have that ability/know-how). This quirk of Inkscape has always annoyed me.

Comment: I'm not unable to code, it would just be a new language and library. I'm more wondering what Inkscape uses? I'll research...

Comment: For extensions, it can use a lot of languages, but the main one is Python - it should not be a hard extension to do, if _ti_is_possible - unfrotunatelly, I don  know if Inskcape feeds the information of what is selected to the extension, or just the drawing. If it does, it should be relatively easy to do.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, no.
You can file a feature request in the [Inkscape bug tracker](http://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape).